# Suddenly am getting "Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed."

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, sql

My virtual machine was working fine, and everything was OK, suddenly, when I tried to connect to central administration, I started having an error saying connection closed and 200 OK http status.

When I look in events viewer, I saw this:

> "Cannot open database
>   "SharePoint_AdminContent_92178c76-6c90-4b06-9129-f821866edr4b"
>   requested by the login. The login failed."

Any idea what would be causing this? I am developing a farm solution, but I haven't done any special configuration lately in my environment. Any help would be appreciated.

I opened SQL, and I can see the + sign on all databases except central admin database. I have my environment installed with only 1 user, so I don't know how this could happen.

Comment: do you have SQL in mixed mode? are there Windows user and SQL user accounts

Comment: was your Admin Content Database deleted or do you see it and its not accessible?

Comment: Hi Glenn, it's not mixed mode, I have 1 active directory user who installed the farm, he has access to everything in sql management studio except for central admin DB now. The database is there, it's not deleted, but it's not accessible at all. I tried to run the configuration wizard, but it's giving me access denied for the central admin DB.

Comment: Can you view the security properties of the CA Content DB in SQL mgmt studio? Does anyone have access?

Comment: Hi Glenn, I can't view anything related to it. I am the only owner of the machine, I am the one who installed SQL server. The + sign is not appearing beside the DB name so I can't expand it to check the security settings.

Comment: The db might be corrupted. I'd maybe try to add-spshelladmin from PowerShell. (As admin) to try to force you to have access. Then I'd check to see if there's something weird w the SQL server Data directory permissions. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks Like you DB is corrupted. Now you have couple of options.

- try to reboot the SQL server
- if you have backup of the Database then restore it.
- If no back then re provision the Central admin

  - Run the SharePoint Config wizard to un provision the Central admin
  - Now again run the SharePoint Config wizard to provision the Central admin.( select the option this server will host central admin)

Comment: Thank you Waqas, I restarted the server, it's a development machine but with a lot of configurations I'd like to keep, there's no snapshot of it. There's no backup from the DB. I ran the configuration wizard, tried to unprovision the central administration, but it gave me an error that it's inaccessible

Comment: try this command for unprovision psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -unprovision

Comment: Where do I execute it from?

Comment: Open the SharePoint PowerShell as an admin and run it

Comment: It worked fine. What should I do next? it said "Configuration of the SharePoint Products has succeeded."

Comment: I ran the configuration wizard again from the start menu, and it gave me the same error: Failed to register SharePoint services, cannot open database (central admin) request by the login. login failed

Comment: now run this psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision

Comment: It worked, it said: "Total number of successful configuration settings: 3" , but I still don't have access to the DB, it's still there inaccessible, and I can't open central admin.

Comment: after running un provision command, did you run the Config wizard and select this server will not host Central admin option? like this http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KZA2cA17qH8/UlhZb0DPxoI/AAAAAAAAALw/VQJ3lv5f4ys/s1600/Untitle2.jpg

Comment: OK let me try again

Comment: It doesn't ask me for this option. 1- option is do not disconnect from this farm or disconnect. 2- central admin port number and NTLM vs Negotiate. It didn't ask me to keep central admin, on the confirmation page by default it says "host central admin web application" and value is yes on the label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49825/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-brittany-rutherford).

Answer (score 2):

Try this within a SQL window inside management studio and let me know what happens.

> USE [SharePoint_AdminContent_92178c76-6c90-4b06-9129-f821866edr4b]
>
> GO
>
> CREATE USER [yourdomain\yourusername] FOR LOGIN [yourdomain\yourusername]
>
> GO
>
> ALTER ROLE [SPDataAccess] ADD MEMBER [yourdomain\yourusername]
>
> GO

Reference: https://joeylicc.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/sharepoints-cannot-open-database-sharepoint_admincontent-requested-by-the-login-error/

Comment: It gave me the same error that the DB cannot be accessed.

Comment: and you're connecting with admin rights? is it failing even after the first USE statement?